# Ajax returning undefined from JSON - Login system & best practice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm receiving an error of undefined when I try and retrieve values in the JSON.  I'm new to ajax / js etc and trying to create an 'elegant' drop down login down.

I've tried various things and read a few of the posts that I've found here but I notice that the layout has changed somewhat and I also notice that I'm using success and now that deprecated.

So could I ask for help in firstly understanding what the problem is and how i solve the undefined issue and secondly what is the best way to achieve this.  I'd prefer not to use deprecated code if I can help it.

I've also noticed that since changing the code so that it gets to the 'success' park of the ajax call, the drop down box no longer rolls back up or displays the error messages.  -.-

Thanks in advance.

The Ajax

```
function validLogin(){
$('.error').hide();
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == ""){
    $('label#usernameError').show();
    $('input#username').focus();
    return false;
}
$('.error').hide();
var password = $('#password').val();
if(password == ""){
    $('label#passwordError').show();
    $('input#password').focus();
    return false;
}

var params = {username: username, password: password};
var url = "../js/loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#statusLogin").show();
$("#statusLogin").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    datatype: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= 'checking...' ;
    },

    success: function(data) {
        alert("success Area ofAjax");

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){
            alert("if data.success Area of Ajax");
            alert(data.message);

        }else{
            alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#errorConsole").html(data.message);
        }

    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}, 'json');
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

if($_POST){

 if($users->userExists($username) === false){
    $data['message'] = "User doesn't exist";
    $data['success'] = false;

}else if($users->userExists($username) === false){
    $data['message'] = 'That username does not exist';
    $data['success'] = false;

}else if($users->emailActivated($username) === false){
    $data['message'] = 'You need to activate the account, please check your email.';
    $data['success'] = false;

}else{

    $login = $users->login($username, $password);

    if($login === false){

        $data['message'] = 'Incorrect Password or username';
        $data['success'] = false;
    }else{
        $data['success'] = true;
        //destroy old session and create new - prevents session fixation attacks
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        //all details are correct - the method returns the id to be sotred as a session
        $_SESSION['id'] = $login;
    }

    echo json_decode($data);
}

}
```

Markup:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ourLoginFormID_JS">
                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" autocomplete="off" class="required" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="required"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ourContactFormElement2">
                        <label> &nbsp; </label>
                        <input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login!" onclick="validLogin(); return false;"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="statusLogin"></div>
                </form>
```

Comment: console.log(error) in your error handler can't be undefined... that's the xhr.

Answer (score 2):

Your if/else/else/else chain only outputs json if the final `else` block executes. You need to move the json_encode call outside the block:

```
if (...) {
} else if (...) {
} else if (...) {
} else {
 ...
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This way your code will output the encoded $data, no matter WHICH of the various if() clauses actually executed.

Comment: FFS! Sleep deprivation -.-

Comment: still undefined though.

Comment: As this answer shows, you should encode the json, not decode it ;)

Comment: apologies, it's been a long couple of days.  Changed to encode, cleared cache, reloaded, still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your undefined error is this:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

Javascript is case sensitive and the property is `dataType` not `datatype`. Because of this, jQuery is not being told to automatically parse the JSON and so you're just getting the JSON string, causing the undefined error on `data.message`.

Also I don't see where you access `$_POST['username']` or where you instantiate the `$users` object, I see `$username` but not `$_POST['username']`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo.  I changed that, no undefined message but it doesn't do much else at the moment.  in the console i see object and all it's methods but it doesn't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: the users object is instantiated in an init.php.  username and password are gained at the start before the ajax is called. Or, have I got something there completely wrong?

Comment: In the ajax success function, is it going into the if or else?

Comment: At the moment it doesn't get to the success part.

It seems to freeze at :    beforeSend: function() {
            document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= 'checking...' ;
        },

Comment: No, nothing.  In the console I see object and a list of its functions.  nothign else

Comment: What are you doing at the end of the ajax with `}, 'json');`? That should just be `});`.

Comment: Removed.  Same result as before.

Comment: Also, are you watching the request in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools (F12)? That's the only way to debug ajax. Look at the Net/Network tab and see what the request/resonse looks like.

Comment: I've had a look and it seems to freeze when calling on the user object PHP Error Message
<b>Fatal error</b>:  
Call to a member function userExists() on a non-object in public_html/js/loginProcessAjax.php

Comment: the object does exist though, it's one of the first things to happen when the init.php is loaded

Comment: I'm guessing you instantiated `$users` in a function or this code is in a function and so it's out of scope, ie it does exist but not in this scope.

Comment: Users is instantiated in init.php.
init is included at the top of every page prior to anything else.

This login is within a header include file, so it's on every page as well.

By that reasoning it should read - instantiate - load header include - login script. ?

Comment: Is it in a function in the include though?

Comment: the login script is within a function within a js helper class if that's what you mean?

Comment: You will have to pass `$users` to the function because otherwise the function won't be able to see it. In PHP you don't automatically get access to variables in the parent/global scope.

Comment: oh ok.  Is is enough to simply do validLogin($users) and update the function with $users as a param as well?  I've done that and now the function doesn't seem to get called at all, no alert boxes etc

Comment: validLogin is your Javascript though? It's the PHP that's the problem because `$users` isn't set. Likely a scope problem. I would var_dump() it at each stage to see what point it disappears. Have a look here for more details about variable scope in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score -1):

A couple of things.  You might want to explicitly use `contentType` parameter of application/json here so that it is clear that you are both sending and receiving JSON.

The main issue is that when sending POST data to PHP that is not form-encoded, `$_POST` will not be populated automitically.  You need to read http raw input like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(!empty($json)) { // replace your if($_POST) with this
    $object = json_decode($json);
    $username = $object->username;
    $password = $object->password;

    // the rest of your code

}
```

Comment: Setting the content type of the response is not required, jQuery does a good job figuring out what the response data type is. Also, jQuery's ajax function automatically uses the form encoded content type for post requests. Reading from the raw stream isn't going to solve a javascript error... this answer doesn't seem to address the error described in the question at all. It isn't "wrong", per se, just not the solution here (or even related). The lack of `json_encode` is the problem, not problems with `$_POST`

Comment: @Chris The response datatype is already specified by his parameters as JSON so autodetect wouldn't be attempted in this case. You are correct that the contentType defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  I was just commenting on perhaps making it clear as to what datatype you are working with on the request as well.  From the code snippet it wasn't clear to me that he was actually trying to access the $_POST variables as would be populated when form encoded contentType was used.